# What does the number after log level indicate in ESP_LOGx messages?

Tags: logging, esp32, esp-idf

Here is the sample program that runs two tasks on the same core with different priorities, where the task function logs the task name, coreId and a demo counter.

```
#include <freertos/FreeRTOS.h>
#include <freertos/task.h>
#include <esp_log.h>

_Noreturn void taskFunction(void *taskParams);

_Noreturn void app_main(void) {
    const char *task1Name = "Running Task 1";
    const char *task2Name = "Running Task 2";
    xTaskCreatePinnedToCore(taskFunction, "Task1", 2048, (void *) task1Name, 1, NULL, 1);
    xTaskCreatePinnedToCore(taskFunction, "Task2", 2048, (void *) task2Name, 2, NULL, 1);
    for (;;);
}

void taskFunction(void *taskParams) {
    int counter = 0;
    const char *taskName = taskParams;
    for (;;) {
        ESP_LOGI(taskName, "on core %d counter %d\r\n", xPortGetCoreID(), ++counter);
        vTaskDelay(1000 / portTICK_RATE_MS);
    }
}
```

and its log

```
I (305) cpu_start: Starting scheduler on PRO CPU.
I (0) cpu_start: Starting scheduler on APP CPU.
I (0) Running Task 2: on core 1 counter 1

I (0) Running Task 1: on core 1 counter 1

0x40080fd4: call_start_cpu1 at D:/SDKs/ESPIDF/components/esp_system/port/cpu_start.c:141

I (1010) Running Task 2: on core 1 counter 2

I (1010) Running Task 1: on core 1 counter 2

I (2010) Running Task 2: on core 1 counter 3

I (2010) Running Task 1: on core 1 counter 3

I (3010) Running Task 2: on core 1 counter 4

I (3010) Running Task 1: on core 1 counter 4

I (4010) Running Task 2: on core 1 counter 5

I (4010) Running Task 1: on core 1 counter 5

E (10315) task_wdt: Task watchdog got triggered. The following tasks did not reset the watchdog in time:
E (10315) task_wdt:  - IDLE (CPU 0)
E (10315) task_wdt: Tasks currently running:
E (10315) task_wdt: CPU 0: main
E (10315) task_wdt: CPU 1: IDLE
E (10315) task_wdt: Print CPU 0 (current core) backtrace
...
...
...

I (16375) Running Task 2: on core 1 counter 12

I (16385) Running Task 1: on core 1 counter 12

I (17375) Running Task 2: on core 1 counter 13

I (17385) Running Task 1: on core 1 counter 13
```

What does the numbers 1010, 2010, ... indicate after log level in parenthesis?

And how can they be same at the start for two different tasks and later after watchdog timer gets triggered they could be different?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's the current time in milliseconds.

They can be the same because your tasks are doing almost nothing; the ESP32 can switch between tasks in well under a millisecond, so they run within the same millisecond of timing, even if not at the exact same time.

You can see for yourself in the [source code](https://github.com/espressif/esp-idf/blob/master/components/log/include/esp_log.h#L352):

```
#define ESP_LOGI( tag, format, ... ) ESP_LOG_LEVEL_LOCAL(ESP_LOG_INFO,    tag, format, ##__VA_ARGS__)
```

and [ESP_LOG_LEVEL_LOCAL](https://github.com/espressif/esp-idf/blob/master/components/log/include/esp_log.h#L441):

```
#define ESP_LOG_LEVEL_LOCAL(level, tag, format, ...) do {               \
        if ( LOG_LOCAL_LEVEL >= level ) ESP_LOG_LEVEL(level, tag, format, ##__VA_ARGS__); \
    } while(0)
```

and [ESP_LOG_LEVEL](https://github.com/espressif/esp-idf/blob/master/components/log/include/esp_log.h#L401):

```
#if CONFIG_LOG_TIMESTAMP_SOURCE_RTOS
#define ESP_LOG_LEVEL(level, tag, format, ...) do {                     \
        if (level==ESP_LOG_ERROR )          { esp_log_write(ESP_LOG_ERROR,      tag, LOG_FORMAT(E, format), esp_log_timestamp(), tag __VA_OPT__(,) __VA_ARGS__); } \
        else if (level==ESP_LOG_WARN )      { esp_log_write(ESP_LOG_WARN,       tag, LOG_FORMAT(W, format), esp_log_timestamp(), tag __VA_OPT__(,) __VA_ARGS__); } \
        else if (level==ESP_LOG_DEBUG )     { esp_log_write(ESP_LOG_DEBUG,      tag, LOG_FORMAT(D, format), esp_log_timestamp(), tag __VA_OPT__(,) __VA_ARGS__); } \
        else if (level==ESP_LOG_VERBOSE )   { esp_log_write(ESP_LOG_VERBOSE,    tag, LOG_FORMAT(V, format), esp_log_timestamp(), tag __VA_OPT__(,) __VA_ARGS__); } \
        else                                { esp_log_write(ESP_LOG_INFO,       tag, LOG_FORMAT(I, format), esp_log_timestamp(), tag __VA_OPT__(,) __VA_ARGS__); } \
    } while(0)
#elif CONFIG_LOG_TIMESTAMP_SOURCE_SYSTEM
#define ESP_LOG_LEVEL(level, tag, format, ...) do {                     \
        if (level==ESP_LOG_ERROR )          { esp_log_write(ESP_LOG_ERROR,      tag, LOG_SYSTEM_TIME_FORMAT(E, format), esp_log_system_timestamp(), tag __VA_OPT__(,) __VA_ARGS__); } \
        else if (level==ESP_LOG_WARN )      { esp_log_write(ESP_LOG_WARN,       tag, LOG_SYSTEM_TIME_FORMAT(W, format), esp_log_system_timestamp(), tag __VA_OPT__(,) __VA_ARGS__); } \
        else if (level==ESP_LOG_DEBUG )     { esp_log_write(ESP_LOG_DEBUG,      tag, LOG_SYSTEM_TIME_FORMAT(D, format), esp_log_system_timestamp(), tag __VA_OPT__(,) __VA_ARGS__); } \
        else if (level==ESP_LOG_VERBOSE )   { esp_log_write(ESP_LOG_VERBOSE,    tag, LOG_SYSTEM_TIME_FORMAT(V, format), esp_log_system_timestamp(), tag __VA_OPT__(,) __VA_ARGS__); } \
        else                                { esp_log_write(ESP_LOG_INFO,       tag, LOG_SYSTEM_TIME_FORMAT(I, format), esp_log_system_timestamp(), tag __VA_OPT__(,) __VA_ARGS__); } \
    } while(0)
#endif //CONFIG_LOG_TIMESTAMP_SOURCE_xxx
#else // !(defined(__cplusplus) && (__cplusplus >  201703L))
#if CONFIG_LOG_TIMESTAMP_SOURCE_RTOS
#define ESP_LOG_LEVEL(level, tag, format, ...) do {                     \
        if (level==ESP_LOG_ERROR )          { esp_log_write(ESP_LOG_ERROR,      tag, LOG_FORMAT(E, format), esp_log_timestamp(), tag, ##__VA_ARGS__); } \
        else if (level==ESP_LOG_WARN )      { esp_log_write(ESP_LOG_WARN,       tag, LOG_FORMAT(W, format), esp_log_timestamp(), tag, ##__VA_ARGS__); } \
        else if (level==ESP_LOG_DEBUG )     { esp_log_write(ESP_LOG_DEBUG,      tag, LOG_FORMAT(D, format), esp_log_timestamp(), tag, ##__VA_ARGS__); } \
        else if (level==ESP_LOG_VERBOSE )   { esp_log_write(ESP_LOG_VERBOSE,    tag, LOG_FORMAT(V, format), esp_log_timestamp(), tag, ##__VA_ARGS__); } \
        else                                { esp_log_write(ESP_LOG_INFO,       tag, LOG_FORMAT(I, format), esp_log_timestamp(), tag, ##__VA_ARGS__); } \
    } while(0)
#elif CONFIG_LOG_TIMESTAMP_SOURCE_SYSTEM
#define ESP_LOG_LEVEL(level, tag, format, ...) do {                     \
        if (level==ESP_LOG_ERROR )          { esp_log_write(ESP_LOG_ERROR,      tag, LOG_SYSTEM_TIME_FORMAT(E, format), esp_log_system_timestamp(), tag, ##__VA_ARGS__); } \
        else if (level==ESP_LOG_WARN )      { esp_log_write(ESP_LOG_WARN,       tag, LOG_SYSTEM_TIME_FORMAT(W, format), esp_log_system_timestamp(), tag, ##__VA_ARGS__); } \
        else if (level==ESP_LOG_DEBUG )     { esp_log_write(ESP_LOG_DEBUG,      tag, LOG_SYSTEM_TIME_FORMAT(D, format), esp_log_system_timestamp(), tag, ##__VA_ARGS__); } \
        else if (level==ESP_LOG_VERBOSE )   { esp_log_write(ESP_LOG_VERBOSE,    tag, LOG_SYSTEM_TIME_FORMAT(V, format), esp_log_system_timestamp(), tag, ##__VA_ARGS__); } \
        else                                { esp_log_write(ESP_LOG_INFO,       tag, LOG_SYSTEM_TIME_FORMAT(I, format), esp_log_system_timestamp(), tag, ##__VA_ARGS__); } \
    } while(0)
#endif //CONFIG_LOG_TIMESTAMP_SOURCE_xxx
```

This last one is where the actual C logging function gets called. As you can see it's passed a timestamp - the system can be configured to select the source of the timestamp.

You can continue tracing this into the [C logging functions](https://github.com/espressif/esp-idf/blob/master/components/log/log.c#L204) if you want to see how the  `printf()` hackery works.

Comment: what do you mean by "two different cpu" they are running on the same core "core 1" i.e. APP CPU?

Comment: its not possible to run two different tasks on the same core at the same time right, can you please explain what is happening here or I should ask another question?

Comment: Edited to clarify the appearance of them running at the same time.